# How to install from two .ISO images?

Tags: windows, mount, wine, iso

I mount the first one, run the Setup (it's a Windows program), and when it asks for DISC 2, I try to unmount the ISO, but it says it can't be unmounted because it's busy, which is obvious.
In Windows, you can unmount the disc while the Setup is still running. My question is if there's any workaround this and mount the second image while the setup is still running?

Thank you.

Comment: Huh?  If you eject the disc the program is running from, it would crash.

Comment: @psusi That's not always true, the program is loaded into memory at the execution time, so if the program doesn't "take for granted" that he can access at any time the file on the medium it has been ran off it won't crash, in fact `Windows` setups spread across multiple media always allow a "hot switch" of the disk at runtime

Comment: @kos, the program has no control over whether it is loaded into memory or not.  The kernel can discard parts of it any time it needs to free up some memory and it will be re-read from disk when needed again.  Of course, if the disk is gone, that's a problem.

Comment: @psusi You're right, but I don't clearly understand how `Windows` executables manage to do so then. Is this a difference between `Windows`' and `Linux`'s kernel? Otherwise there must be a way at least in `Windows` to force the program to be fully loaded, or I couldn't explain how switching disks is possible in `Windows`

Comment: @kos, from what I've seen, when you run an installer program like that, it is actually a stub that extracts the real installer to your hd then runs that.

Answer (score 0):

Just mount both images at the same time, there's no real need to unmount the first one.

---

On a side note: the problem is probably the fact that `wine` itself is preventing the image to be unmounted, overriding the specific executable's default behavior which wouldn't.